# Mounting HTFS Disk on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, sco

I got my hand on a harddrive that contains a SCO Openserver 5 and I need to access the data inside. Is there any way I can just mount and start copy-pasting the files? I've googled around and mostly get some instruction from 2000s that don't work. It looks like the Linux kernel needs to be compiled to support the filesystem.

Are there any distros that supports this by default? If not, how could I access the drive without sharing it on the network?

Comment: And maybe we need a SCO or HTFS tag? Anyone can help adding the tags?

Comment: You can check supported filesystems on your machine in /proc/filesystems. I checked mine and htfs isn't in there. HTFS / SCO Openserver are old and little used. This is probably the reason for not including compiled HTFS module in distributions. Features like this are rarely completely dropped from the kernel, but you probably have to compile it yourself from sources (and for the kernel version on your system). Make an image using dd from the disk, work with that image and put the original disk in a safe place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: as author in one of the links commented, it would be best to make a copy of the raw disk before trying any sort of SCO fsck or trying to mount the filesystem.

I see your options as:

1. Connect and mount the drive on an existing SCO system or Boot the hard drive into SCO OpenServer (or SCO rescue disk if you have one) and then copy your data off via network or removable media. I realize that this is not what you were asking but may be the shortest route depending on what you have available. You may be able to find a copy of SCO on Ebay if you don't have one (finding compatible hardware may be interesting).
2. Get Linux to mount the SCO HTFS filesystem [via these instructions](https://www.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec1linuxfs.html).